# Removing the # in Angular URLs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have an AngularJS (1.4.5) website that is placed on a apache2 server with a small NodeJS instance that serves the communication with the backend and also hosts the website, I use apache2 `sites-available.conf` file for redirecting the port

The URL looks like this today:

```
http://prod.mywebsiteurl.com/myapp/#/mp
```

The last path is dynamic, when the Angular app is started, it takes the last parameter with: (I've configured this with $routeProvider

```
dynamicUrl = $routeParams.dynamicUrl;
```

in the `init()` function.

When I enable `html5mode` with:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I can't access the website:

```
http://prod.mywebsiteurl.com/myapp/mp
```

It gives an apache2 error.

```
Cannot GET /MP (404)
```

However, if I type the old address, with the `#` it redirects to the site **without** the `#`.

Any idea how to solve this? Is this a apache2 configuration? If so? How do I do it? I am a real apache2 noob.

I think I have to have a .htaccess file and use this little rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

I found it on this page: https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

But I'm using a Node as the webserver, so I really don't know where to place the file, the server is a Ubuntu server. I placed it in the NodeJS root, but that did not seem to work very well.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, for your angular app you have just one entry point (index.html) and then the internal routing will do everything for you. What you have to do in node is every call you get return the index.html.

Unfortunately sou did not state what you were using in node, if a framework or not. Assuming you have an express instance running, you can do as follows:

```
var express = require('express');

var server = express();
server.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

server.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var port = 8000;
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

`server.get('/*'` this will accept any call basically and will always return index.html. so your angular app can start